# Get list of all users with the id of group in which user is member using azure graph api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want the list of groups in which the user is a member of the Azure AD B2C group using the azure graph API in a single request.

I am able to get the list of users but however the **MemberOf** property of the Microsoft.Graph.User class is null.

```
 // Get all users (one page)
var result = await _graphClient.Users
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Filter("userType eq 'member'")
    .Select($"id,displayName,identities,memberOf")
    .GetAsync();
```

Here I am getting all users, but the groups are not returned in which the user is a member.

Is it possible to get the group's name in the above single request?

Yes, I know I can call another API separately for each and every user, but I want in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by including `memberOf` as [`Expand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter) parameter. Something like:

```
var result = await _graphClient.Users
    .Request(queryOptions)
    .Filter("userType eq 'member'")
    .Select($"id,displayName,identities")
    .Expand("memberOf")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: I tried the above, But now it does not return any users!!!

Comment: I read somewhere that this is still in beta version!!

Comment: I used it against v1 of the API. I tried it in Graph Explorer and this was my request URL: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=memberOf&$select=id,displayName,identities&$filter=userType eq 'member'`.

Comment: However, Still, I am not getting any records!!! I think it is permission issues!! what do you think?

Comment: I am not sure but I would imagine. Do you have permissions to list groups (Group.ReadAll or GroupMember.ReadAll or Directory.ReadAll)? Please try to run this in Graph Explorer. It will tell you exactly the permissions needed.

Comment: Yes, I can list the Groups, add the member into the group, remove the member from the group by graph API.

Comment: Graph API has the Directory.Read.All permission but the Group.ReadAll and GroupMember.ReadAll permission is not there.

Comment: Graph Explorer ask me for this permissions: User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read, User.ReadWrite, User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

Comment: I just tried it in my code and I was able to get the "member of" information. In my case, the application has "Directory.Read.All" permission.